# blender having trouble a consistent mesh for 3D printing

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

1. I imported svg file.
2. Scaled it up.
3. Entered the top ortho view with <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>A</kbd> twice.
5. In Object mode, on the *Toolshelf* pressed *Geometry to Origin*.
6. Applied the scale of the object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
7. Converted the curve to mesh with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
8. In Edit mode selected all faces, pressed <kbd>X</kbd> key and choosed *Limited Dissolve*.

With all this done I'm left with one face which can't extruded to form a model for 3d printing.
Could anyone explain how to resolve this issue?

[image: screenshot of the problem area]

The problem area of the mesh is at the middle right corner of the flower.

Comment: If your mesh is just a plane then it is non-manifold geometry and won't be printed. If it really can't be extruded, [upload it](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit your question with that link or add comment with it.

Comment: Why the limited dissolve? Sure there probably where lots of ugly triangles but who cares about them when 3D printing? My advice, skip the limited dissolve. Then extrude and run the 3D printing check.